# Open tracing instrumentation for ForkJoinPool.commonPool()

Tags: spring-boot, jaeger, opentracing

My application extensively uses `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> someService(context, args));` & we rely on supplyAsync to use `ForkJoinPool.commonPool()` thread pool to get the service run in its own thread.

Is there a way to instrument someService call in open tracing without passing in a custom `Executor` as argument to supplyAsync() ? I'm using spring and jaeger and have the below dependency

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.opentracing.contrib</groupId>
            <artifactId>opentracing-spring-jaeger-cloud-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, the design of `ForkJoinPool.commonPool()` makes it impossible to actually replace that pool programmatically with an instrumented version. So the only workaround is to do it via bytecode manipulation.

The [OpenTelemetry Java Automatic Instrumentation](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation) libraries perform a lot of magic to be able to take care of correctly propagating context through async/concurrency primitives, you may want to give them a try.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. With open telemetry api not in its GA yet, I'm feeling nervous to start using it. For now i have settled with using a custom instrumented executor to achieve the tracing.